# ng serve fail not recognizing bootstrap installed in node modules

Tags: node.js, angular, bootstrap-4, node-modules

I have an angular 5 project. I have installed bootstrap 4

I have attempted to point to bootstrap in my angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"

      ],
```

I have attempted to import via an `@import` statement in my styles.css

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I keep getting this error. I think it may be an issue deeper than just angular maybe something in node but I am not sure.

here is the of the error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:438:37)
    at /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:274:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:189:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:201:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:228:20)
    at LazyResult.async (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:225:27)
    at LazyResult.then (/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:131:21)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/styles.css 3:10-186
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include the `bootstrap.css` file in the styles array in `.angular-cli.json`, you will have all the bootstrap classes ready to use. I don't think you have to add another import statement in the css file.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thats why I said I tried it via the angular cli and also importing. I did not do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

issue was with bootstrap version

did this.

I downgraded bootstrap with following steps.
Uninstall bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3:
npm uninstall bootstrap --save
Then installed bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2:
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 --save

I did not remove ^ because package-lock.json will handle it.